# How to get all img src from a row in MySql?

Tags: html, mysql, sql

With current `MySql` query is able to fetch `src` from the first `img` tag.

Query:

```
SELECT substr(substr(textfield , locate('src="', textfield ) + 5), 1, 
                     locate('"', substr(textfield , locate('src="', textfield ) + 5)) - 1) as 'imgurl' 
from pages where field1 ='data' and field2 = 'nothing';
```

Need to fetch all the `src` in all `img` tag in the cell of a row.

Example:

table column has `id` and `text`.

textfield has

```
some random content <img src='https://www.fakeurl.com/folder/image.jpeg'> 
and also <img src="https://www.fakeurl.com/folder/image.jpg"> and also <img 
src='/folder/image.jpeg'> and some additional content
```

Need to fetch all `src` from this `textfield` column using a `query` or a `function` or `procedure` in MySQL.

Result needed is:

```
https://www.fakeurl.com/folder/image.jpeg
https://www.fakeurl.com/folder/image.jpg
/folder/image.jpeg
```

What is needed to be modified to get result, or using some other query?

Comment: Are you saving entire HTML pages in a database?

Comment: There's a few ideas here you could use: [SQL split values to multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows)

Comment: SQL and HTML are really not friends as HTML can be expressed in ways that are really difficult to parse with a regular expression.

Comment: It's not wierd to store HTML in SQL when you are using a CMS.. But it is kind off wierd to parse HTML with SQL because it's better done on application code.. i assume you are not using MySQL 8.0+?

Comment: Yes. I am saving entire html in the database. my mysql database version is 8.0.11. I would like to have this done on mysql instead of application code.

Comment: For future reference please don't tag your questions with irrelevant tags. You may think you are attracting additional eyeballs to your question but really you just want people who are expert in MySQL.